# Не работает json_encode для результата запроса к бд

Tags: php, массивы, база-данных, json, json-encode

Здравствуйте!
Есть запрос к бд, после его обработки результат выглядит следующим образом:

Вывод с помощью:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    var_dump($row);
    echo "</br>";
}
```

Результат:

```
array(2) { ["home"]=> string(15) "Kuban Krasnodar" ["away"]=> string(3) "Ufa" }

array(2) { ["home"]=> string(17) "Fratangelo, Bjorn" ["away"]=> string(13) "Bhambri, Yuki" } 

array(2) { ["home"]=> string(13) "VfL Wolfsburg" ["away"]=> string(15) "Bayern Mnchen" } 

array(2) { ["home"]=> string(20) "St Patricks Athletic" ["away"]=> string(13) "Galway United" }
```

Помогите упаковать результат в json.
Я пробовал такой способ:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $rows[] = array('data' => $row);
}
json_encode($rows);
```

И даже такой:

```
$event = Array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $event[0] = $row["home"];
    $event[1] = $row["away"];
    array_push($events, $event);
}
json_encode($events);
```

И ни тот ни другой не сработал.

**Проблема решена**

Очень помогла функция json_last_error(). Оказалось, что json_encode выбрасывал ошибку JSON_ERROR_UTF8. Видимо какой-то косяк с кодировками. После замены косячных символов с помощью функции:

```
function clean($string) {
    return preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9" "\-]/', '', $string);
}
```

все заработало.

Answer (score 1):

`json_encode` ничего не выводит (и не должен). Он просто возвращает данные строкой (и вообще это [чистая функция](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8)). Если хотите сразу же выводить - предваряйте конструкцией `echo`.

Comment: Это я знаю, спасибо. Здесь эта строчка как часть примера. Но если попытаться вывести, то вывод будет пустой.

Comment: Разрешите вам не поверить. У вас либо array_push не отрабатывает на несуществующем массиве, либо ошибки заглушены.

Comment: Добавил к началу файла

Comment: Добавил к началу файла`ini_set('display_errors', 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);` - безрезультатно, вывод пустой. array_push отрабатывает и по завершению цикла while массив events выглядит  как и должен: array(4) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "Niort" [1]=> string(12) "Valenciennes" } [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(15) "Kuban Krasnodar" [1]=> string(3) "Ufa" } [2]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(17) "Fratangelo, Bjorn" [1]=> string(13) "Bhambri, Yuki" } [3]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(13) "VfL Wolfsburg" [1]=> string(15) "Bayern Mnchen" } }.

Comment: Используются ли неймспейсы? function_exists('json_encode') отвечает корректно? Если это *nix-систем, пакет php5-json н месте?

Comment: function_exists('json_encode') - работает корректно. php5-json: `Package: php5-json Status: install ok installed`. Про неймспейсы, если честно, ничего не знаю.

Comment: Проверил, json создается, но только для < 3 записей. Если попробовать больше, то вывод пустой.